# ¿Qué tipos de nested browsing context existen?

Tags: html

Estaba leyendo la [documentación para `<object>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object) y vi que representa un recurso externo, que puede ser una imagen, un *nested browsing context*, o un recurso a ser gestionado por un plugin.

[Yendo un poco más lejos](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#browsing-context), he visto que una ventana o pestaña de navegador contiene un *browsing context*, así como un `<iframe>` o un `<frameset>`, y que un anidamiento (*nesting*) puede tener varias capas de profundidad.

Lo que no me queda claro es ¿qué tipos de *nested browsing contexts* podemos poner dentro de un *object?*  Imágenes y plugins, ok, pero [*non capisco*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/non_capisco) que otros contextos pueden existir...

Answer (score 0):

Puede que esté equivocado, pero creo que (salvo excepciones) las imágenes y los plugins no se considerarían *nested browsing contexts* (contextos de navegación anidados) porque no tendrían contexto propio.

Algunos ejemplos de contenido que puedes poner el el `data` de un elemento `object` y con los que se crearía un contexto anidado:

- Un archivo HTML (estático). Ej:

  ```
  <object data="mipagina.html"></object>
  ```
- Un archivo de un lenguaje de script (dinámico). Ej:

  ```
  <object data="mipagina.php"></object>
  ```
- Una URL. Ej:

  ```
  <object data="http://www.alvaromontoro.com"></object>
  ```
- Una imagen en formato SVG. Ej:

  ```
  <object data="miImage.svg"></object>
  ```

Aunque realmente los tres primeros casos (y ya puestos, también el cuarto) son el mismo tipo: código de marcado (*mark-up language*). El primero es HTML estático; el segundo es una página dinámica, pero el resultado es HTML; la URL redirigirá a contenido HTML; y el último es en formato SVG, que está basado en XML.

En esos cuatro casos, se crearía un nuevo contexto de navegación anidado al contexto que incluye la etiqueta `object`, y en el que podrías tener código con el que se accediera al contexto creador usando `window.parent`.

Comment: ¿Puede que el soporte ya sea casi "legacy"? Esto funciona en JSFiddle `<iframe src="https://jsfiddle.net"></iframe>`, pero esto no `<object data="https://jsfiddle.net"></object>`

Comment: A mí me funcionan las dos usando "https://jsfiddle.net". No sé si será alguna configuración de mi navegador

Comment: há! En OSX 10.9.5, solo me ha funcionado en Safari, pero no en Chrome o Firefox...

Comment: Que raro. En Windows 10 Pro me da el mismo resultado en Chrome, Edge, FF e IE11.